Upsert element in column that contains arrays
I have a PostgreSQL table that contains a column with array of strings, and I use SQLAlchemy to manage it.
I would like to build an "upsert" function, so if a specific cell contains as example {'a', 'b'}, and I try to update it with 'b', the output should be still {'a', 'b'}.
Is it possible?

If you can map those letters to numbers, intarray offers set operations that behave the way you want. Otherwise the update can append the element, unnest the array, grab a distinct of that, then array_agg(). You can also make those elements into keys of a jsonb - setting an existing key just overwrites the value, setting a new key adds it. You could also consider normalisation, in which case you could use a regular upset like merge or insert..on conflict.

You can try to do this using array functions like when anyarray @> anyarray  do nothing else append . Show your table and data example.

Either way you have to de-duplicate merged values, consider writing your own plain sql function like this:
create function public.array_unique(a anyarray) returns anyarray
  language sql
as
$$
  select array (
    select distinct v from unnest(a) as b(v)
  )
$$;

then you can check the result
select public.array_unique(array ['a', 'b'] || array ['a'])

and then adapt it with
insert into distributors (did, dname)
values (5, '{a,b}'), (6, '{a}')
on conflict (did) do update set dname = public.array_unique(dname || excluded.dname);

